# Scroll a long drop down menu horizontally with buttons at both ends?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu with categories and sub-categories.

I have to show a menu in form of drop down i.e category on top and the sub categories in drop down menu.

I have tried to include slider in the menu, but the problem is I have 19 categories that can't be shown in the menu bar at a time, so I have to scroll the menu horizontally with buttons at both ends.

The problem is if I include scroll the drop down menu disappears.

Do you have any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post code and efforts

Comment: i cant add images for this quesition

Comment: We do not want images. We want example code of what you have done so far.

Comment: i have used http://als.musings.it/ this plugin to scroll the menu but with this the dropdown is not showing